# Adding up two structs by field

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame schema as follows (in PySpark):

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 2022: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_1: int (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 2021: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_1: int (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_3: double (nullable = true)
```

I want to add `2021` and `2022` columns into one column `AGG` such that it will contain the sum of `2021` and `2022` for each row in the DataFrame.

I tried the following:

```py
df.select(
    'ID',
    (F.col("2021") + F.col("2022")).alias("AGG")
).printSchema()
```

Where the desired output schema should be:

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AGG: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_1: int (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- val_3: double (nullable = true)
```

But it seems that spark only supports adding numeric types.
Is there a way to add them implicitly without writing it directly for each field in the struct?

Comment: Can you add a sample dataframe to achieve the same schema and the reproducable dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't addition to struct columns that way. You need to create a new struct column by summing the nested fields.

You can use a list comprehension over the list of inner fields to create a new column like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


def add_struct(common_fields, s1, s2):
    return F.struct(*[
        (s1[f] + s2[f]).alias(f) for f in common_fields
    ])


# get list of struct fields from schema
fields = df.select("2022.*").columns

df.select(
    'ID',
    add_struct(fields, F.col("2021"), F.col("2022")).alias("AGG")
)
```